# AsEnumerable and Query Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a rather complex Linq expression written using query syntax.  Simplified, it looks like:

```
var query = 
    from a in ctx.A
    from b in ctx.B
    where a.Bid == b.Id
    select new MyType()
    {
        Foo = a.Foo,
        Bar = b.Bar
    }
```

I have to modify the query to set a property on the new instance of MyType in a manner that cannot be evaluated by the query provider.  The result set fairly small, so it is reasonable to use .AsEnumerable().  I found an [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386943(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows how to do this in a simple case

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from product in products.AsEnumerable()
    select product;
```

How do I use AsEnumerable() in my more complex case?  That is, how do I achieve something like

```
var query = 
    from a in ctx.A
    from b in ctx.B
    where a.Bid == b.Id
    AsEnumerableGoesHereSomehow
    select new MyType()
    {
        Foo = a.SomeClientSideCalculation(),
        Bar = b.Bar
    }
```

I don't want to perform the join and filtering client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to reduce {a=a,b=b} to just the properties you actually need, but you can use this as a start:

```
var query =( 
    from a in ctx.A
    from b in ctx.B
    where a.Bid == b.Id
    select new 
    {
        a = a,
        b = b
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x=>new MyType {
      Foo=Something(x.a),
      Bar=x.b
    });
```

Comment: In reality there are quite a few properties.  It seems like quite a bit of duplication to list the properties in the projection and again when creating the instance, but perhaps that is the only solution.

Comment: You can also create a class that accepts your properties, and you can query a different (readonly) property that calls your function (and possibly cache it).  Then you wouldn't have to repeat it.